# use controller in actionPerformed method - needs to be final?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm playing around with the MVC pattern and I am stuck.

My simple application (where you can roll dice) has a MainView class that creates and holds a few other Views like ButtonPanelView (which has buttons..). MainView is created by my MainController. MainController also has my rollDice method which will call the diceModel class and change the value.

Now, my rollDice Button is in die ButtonPanelView and thats where the ActionListener is, too. I'm trying to call controller.rollDice() from within the actionPerformed method, but the error says "Variable mainController is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final".
I don't know how to do that, because my this.mainController can't be final, since it is in the Constructor. Here's my code:

```
public class ButtonPanelView extends JPanel{

    private MainController mainController;
    private JButton rollDiceBtn = new JButton("roll dice");
    private JPanel pan = new JPanel();

    public ButtonPanelView(MainController mainController){
        this.mainController = mainController;
        add(pan);
        pan.add(rollDiceBtn);

        rollDiceBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                mainController.rollDice();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Why are you adding your Controller into your View? It should be the other way round isn't it?

Comment: Because I thought the actionPerformed method should always be in the view, where the button is. I need a way to access the rollDice method thats in the controller from the actionPerformed method.

Also: If I have for instance a JTextArea and the user changes the text (for instance by writing their name), I need the controller in the view to take the data (in this case the user name) and give it to the model.
Don't I need the controller in the view for that?

Comment: If you do it that way, you defeat the purpose of MVC which is to decouple your codes. If you want to separate out the View(UI) and the logic, you don't code the logic in the View. You code the logic in the controller instead.

Comment: So where does the actionPerformed method go then?

Comment: In this example http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html (see code sample 5) the view knows about the controller, controller knows about view and model, model doesn't know about the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve the compilation error by using the `OuterClass.this` notation for referencing `mainController` within the anonymous `ActionListener` class you create in the constructor:

```
 rollDiceBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            ButtonPanelView.this.mainController.rollDice();
        }
    });
```

Comment: So the other question I have now is if it is okay to have the controller in the view?
There was another answer here 1 minute ago with another approach, where I didn't need the controller at all in the view. Seems like it was deleted already. I liked that approach too, maybe whoever posted it can post it again?

Comment: Please post an another question that focuses on the design issue (there should only be a single question per each post).